# Check for a product category in a hooked function for WooCommerce products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, taxonomy-terms

I want to check the category of WooCommerce products in **function.php**.

That is my code:

```
function for_preorder()
{
///// DISPLAY something if category id = 50 
}
add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product','for_preorder');
```

How to check for a product category for a WooCommerce product?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `has_term()` WordPress conditional function to check for a category like:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product','for_preorder'); 
function for_preorder() {
    global $product;

    $categories = array( 50 ); // Here define your categories term Ids, slugs or names

    if ( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
        echo '<p>' . __("DISPLAY something here") . '</p>';
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: I use **get_the_terms(get_the_id(),'product_cat');** , i hope they are similar. Thanks anyway

Comment: @AmericanJewelry get_the_terms() is heavier and more complicated to handle, but should work too.

Answer (score 1):

```
if( has_term( 50, 'product_cat' ) ) {
 // do something if current product in the loop is in product category with ID 50
}
```

Or, if you pass the product ID in the `for_preorder()` function, you can do:

```
if( has_term( 50, 'product_tag', 971 ) ) {
    // do something if product with ID = 971 has tag with ID = 50
}
```